# Should the schema of my database in mobile and web app be the same?

Tags: mysql, django, mobile, xamarin

I have designed the schema of my django website's database in this fashion.

Person:

1. Name
2. Age
3. Gender etc.

Car:

1. Foreign Key to Person
2. Car name
3. Car colour 
   etc..

Bike :

1. Foreign key to Person
2. Bike colour etc..

I have converted this into an API as well using django-tastypie. I want to build a mobile app for this using xamarin. The app will have a database for storing these values. However, my Java/C# approach for storing these values would be something like

```
class person{

String name;
int age;  
String gender;
List<Car> listofcars;
List<Bike> listofbikes;

}
```

This is different from how the database is structured.

What is the efficient approach in this scenario?

1.) Should my app database schema be exactly the same as my server database schema ? This way synchronizing values between the server and client is easy. But to get the list of bikes or cars, I need to perform multiple queries.

2.) Or should I develop a different schema for my app that will make it easy for me to develop the app. The only drawback being synchronization will be not easy.

Comment: No, they dont have to be the same - it needs to be in sync with the API, to minimize serialization, etc..

Answer (score 1):

## Yes... <sub><sup>sort of</sup></sub>

[A database schema is just an abstract formal description of how you are storing your data.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_schema). Django models or MySQL DDL definitions are just ways of expressing this abstract concept in a concrete way.

For example, both your django models and C# code describe this abstract idea:

> A `person` has a `name`, `age`, `gender` and can have a collection of `bikes` and `cars`.

Ultimately, if your mobile app, API and django web app are going to be able to communicate, they *must* contain and share the exact same information. Otherwise, your system will lose information between transfers - for example if the app omitted age, and django omitted gender, after a few calls none of your databases would have either.

Do your mobile app and django app have to have a schema that comes from *the exact same place*, maybe, but that will certainly be harder for very little pay off. For example, as part of your build strategy you could have django produce the DDL for building the table, then pass that to the app.